Unable to generate stable spark discharge
I am trying to generate spark discharge between 2 electrodes with an air gap of ~1mm. I am using the circuit shown here for the discharge. I did see some spark between the 2 electrodes but my diode and resistor broke down after 10-15 s with loud sound. What am I doing wrong here?
V1: PS350/5000V-25W
R1: 10k/1W
D1: NTE518
C1: 615R150GAD25


While the discharge is active the air gap is conducting. In that state, which components do you calculate as having the 5kV potential across them?

What's the voltage rating on your resistor?

It’s a regular resistor with 1w power rating

You don't need the diode. Use a high voltage resistor. Or, chain a bunch of low voltage resistors in series. The number you need should be 5000V divided by the working voltage of each resistor. Go one more to be safe. For example, you have 400V rated resistors. Do 5000V/400V. That's 12 and change. Make it 13. If your superstitious, make it 14. The exact resistance value doesn't really matter. (Until your application has a reason the values matter) C1 Needs to have same voltage as your supply or higher.

Thanks this makes sense, I’ll try this and update you.

Where did you get the resistor value? Assuming that the voltage source doesn't get loaded down, the power in R1 is enormous. R1 should be much larger.
If R1 is 10 Meg, the peak power is still 2.5 Watts.
Note that the simulation doesn't include the spark gap. If we assume that it arcs at 4 kV and fully discharges the cap, then the cycle repeats at the red line.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab


I have set a current limit on the power supply to 0.2mA
